# Multiple XML to DOM

Tags: php, xml

I  have multiple XML feeds with the same scheme and want to combine them to one bundle. I currently save 1 file like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->load( 'http://FEEDURL.COM/FEED.PHP' ); 
$dom->encoding='UTF-8';
$dom->save( 'data.xml' ); /* <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> */
```

I need this script to load multiple feeds and all save them to the one file called data.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use `importNode` in DOM.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php